# Creating a IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

I'm using xUnit and it doesn't have a way to determine if 2 `IEnumerable<T>` are equal if `T` is custom type.

I've tried using `LINQ SequenceEqual` but again as the instances of `T` are different this returns false;

Here is a basic test with a non-working `IEqualityComparer`

```
    [Fact]
    public void FactMethodName()
    {
        var one = new[] { new KeywordSchedule() { Id = 1 } };
        var two = new[] { new KeywordSchedule() { Id = 1 } };

        Assert.Equal(one, two, new KeywordScheduleComparer());
    }

public class KeywordScheduleComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<KeywordSchedule>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<KeywordSchedule> x, IEnumerable<KeywordSchedule> y)
    {
        return Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) || (x != null && y != null && x.SequenceEqual(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<KeywordSchedule> obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;

        return unchecked(obj.Select(e => e.GetHashCode()).Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a + b));  // BAD
    }
}
```

I'm using this in an integration test, so I insert data from a IEnumerable into a DB at the start, then call my SUT to retrieve data from DB and compare.

If you can help me get a collection comparison working I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just verified that this works fine with xUnit.net 1.9.2:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
{
    public bool Equals(MyClass x, MyClass y)
    {
        return x.ID == y.ID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyClass obj)
    {
        return obj.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class ExampleTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestForEquality()
    {
        var obj1 = new MyClass { ID = 42, Name = "Brad" };
        var obj2 = new MyClass { ID = 42, Name = "Joe" };

        Assert.Equal(new[] { obj1 }, new[] { obj2 }, new MyClassComparer());
    }
}
```

So I'm not 100% clear why you need the extra comparer. Just the single comparer should be sufficient.

Comment: Ah thanks, I wasnt too far off. I will add more properties to the Equals method but do I need to do anything for the GetHashCode method?

Comment: Technically you're supposed to implement GetHashCode, but if the comparer is for xUnit.net only, you can skip it, as we don't use GetHashCode. Just leave yourself a note to implement it if you ever decide to use the thing for real. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, your implementation is pending. You implemented custom comparer for `IEnumerable<KeywordSchedule>` but forgot to implement the same for `KeywordSchedule`.

`x.SequenceEqual` Still uses `Comparer<T>.Default` so it goes for reference comaprison and hence result is false.

```
public class KScheduleComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeywordSchedule>
{
    public bool Equals(KeywordSchedule x, KeywordSchedule y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;                
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeywordSchedule obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then modify your Equals method in `KeywordScheduleComparer` class as below

```
public class KeywordScheduleComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<KeywordSchedule>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<KeywordSchedule> x, IEnumerable<KeywordSchedule> y)
    {
        return Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) || (x != null && y != null && x.SequenceEqual(y, new KScheduleComparer()));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<KeywordSchedule> obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;

        return unchecked(obj.Select(e => e.GetHashCode()).Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a + b));  // BAD
    }
}
```

Comment: So put public bool Equals(IEnumerable<KeywordSchedule> x, IEnumerable<KeywordSchedule> y)
 on the KeywordSchedule class?

Comment: No It should be in `KeywordScheduleComparer ` class. If not clear I'll update full code

Comment: Thanks. Why are there 2 comparers?

Comment: @Jon Because you need to be able to compare two different types of things, the underlying items, and sequences of items.  If you only needed to compare one type you'd only need one comparer.

Comment: Your first comparer should return `obj.Id.GetHashCode()` instead.  That `Id` is very important.

Comment: @Jon I think servy answered your question. Or you could simply do `bool res = one.SequenceEqual(two, new KScheduleComparer());` and you can get rid of second comparer.

Comment: @BradWilson Thats what I was doing I think in question I think so not sure the difference

Answer (score 0):

You could do this more elegantly using [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/documentation) library. It has plenty assertion methods for collections.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected bool Equals(MyClass other)
    {
        return ID == other.ID;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((MyClass) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (ID*397) ^ (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }
}

public class ExampleTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestForEquality()
    {
        var obj1 = new MyClass { ID = 42, Name = "Rock" };
        var obj2 = new MyClass { ID = 42, Name = "Paper" };
        var obj3 = new MyClass { ID = 42, Name = "Scissors" };
        var obj4 = new MyClass { ID = 42, Name = "Lizard" };

        var list1 = new List<MyClass> {obj1, obj2};
        list1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(obj3, obj4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I agree, that FluentAssertions are a good solution to many such issues, your example does not directly address the question. I.e. you are not asserting if two lists are equal (you only have one) and, if I remember correctly, default use of `BeEquivalentTo` disregards the order of items in compared collections, which is probably not the desired result (as the example in the question used `SequenceEqual`). Also, when using FluentAssetions, you actually don't need to have `Equals` overriden in the `MyClass` - you can provide comparison rules to FluentAssertions to compare by properties.