# Using lambdas to filter using a multidimensional array or map of filter parameters?

Tags: c#, arrays, lambda

Given that I have a collection of objects and a collection of key=value pairs, how would I construct a lambda (or, if lambda is inappropriate, another expression) so that it filters the original collection based on the settings of the second.

Example: a collection of missions and given a map contains type=flight and location=USA, return all flight missions in the USA.

This question is in conjunction with another question, but as they are separate things I made two questions out of it.

Assume I have something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> filters; //type and location are keys, flight and USA are the values, respectively
List<Mission> missions;
```

Existing currently we have something like:

```
var badIds;
return missions.Where(x => !badIds.contains(x.ids)))
    .Select(x => x.ids);
```

The thing is, in this case I have to know at compile time that I want to filter based on ids and use a single dimension array like collection to do it. I want to use two dimensions and include not only what values I'm looking for, but what parameter to look in for it while also dynamically expanding the number of filter operations based on the number of parameters. They may specify one, the other, both, more parameters, less, in any combination, etc (0 parameters may be a special case, but that's easy enough).

I want something like:

```
for ( KeyValuePair kvp in filters )
{
    missions = missions.Where(x => x.(kvp.Key) == kvp.Value);
}
//I'm new to lambdas and C# so this is probably terrible.
```

Comment: Do you want to do this on a **certain type** like flight missions? If yes, then it can be easily constructed. If you want to make it super-universal, not type-related, then it is possble using reflection, but do you really need this? Anyway, it would be great if you provide any code example like *"I have **this** and I want something like **that**:..."*.

Comment: Often text is not the best medium to explain a programming issue. You should at least show some (pseudo-)code and maybe you've even tried something, then show it.

Comment: if you need this for a webservice, you could may have a look on oData

Comment: For the GroupBy method to work you need a class that inherits IEqualityComparer<>.  See following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720582/creating-a-iequalitycomparerienumerablet.  Use for Where or distinct methods IComparable

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I have added some additional information and code examples to further explain the question. Thank you.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  I have added some additional information and code examples to further explain the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From your description, this is what I gather you are trying to do:

```
IEnumerable<Mission> FindMissions(IEnumerable<Mission> missions, string flight, string location)
{
    var results = new List<Mission>();
    foreach (Mission m in missions)
    {
        if (m.Type == flight && m.Location == location) 
        {
            results.Add(m);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: That's the rigid way to do it. What if they don't specify a type, but specify a location and date? Or date only? You'd need something like (number of searchable parameters)! functions to do it all. Also, you typo'd type as flight, the variable name should be type, the runtime value may be flight.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a more generic way of searching. I would recommend looking at the [Specification Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my own solution to this so it can be judged. Let me know what you guys think.

```
for ( KeyValuePair kvp in filters )
{
    missions = missions.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(kvp.Key).GetValue(x, null) == kvp.Value;
}
```

I've never done reflection before so the performance implications are unknown.